# About the operation of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is the text from Gregory Lee's Abstract algebra:
[image]

I know $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are permutation letters. But I don't understand how the operation would go. How does $(\sigma \circ \tau)(1)=\sigma(\tau(1))=\sigma(3)=3$ run for example? What does the number in $\sigma( )$ mean?

Comment: The inputs are in the top row; the outputs on the bottom.  So $\sigma(1)$ means look for the $1$ in the top row, find the entry below it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A permutation $\sigma$ is a *function* $\{1,2,\dots, n\}\to \{1,2,\dots, n\}$ which has an inverse (reversible, which is equivalent to be one-to-one for a finite set).

In the given example, $n=3$, and 
$$\sigma(1)=2,\ \sigma(2)=1,\ \sigma(3)=3\,.$$